# Save As CSV puts extra comma on header line

Tags: qgis

I was attempting to save a Shapefile point file as a CSV.  My Shapefile only has one attribute (id).  I use the `Save Vector Layer as...` tool by right clicking on the shapefile I want to convert.

I have chosen `Comma Separated Value (CSV)` from the Format

I select the folder and file name I want to save the file as.

I left encoding to `UTF-8`

I have selected the `id` field I want to export from the shapefile

I set GEOMETRY to `AS_YX`

I set LINEFORMAT to `CRLF`

I set SEPARATOR to `COMMA`

I leave WRITE_BOM as `NO`  *btw, what is this?

I then save the file.  Another program I was using to read that file kept giving me grief until I opened the file in Excel and then saved it again.  It was driving my nuts.  I happen to open the file in Wordpad just to see the raw data once and noticed the header line.

The file had the following data in it:

```
Y,X,id,
46.5139490255807,-110.990074324009,1
46.4904918688525,-110.989960260943,1
46.4904314614628,-110.992750419033,2
46.5127715775017,-110.992811837607,2
46.4904405225755,-110.999357302811,3
46.5084993401582,-110.999515236288,3
46.5005246052244,-111.002094816409,4
46.4976285297097,-111.002077268245,4
46.496432607856,-111.002182557229,5
46.4907244366764,-111.002112364573,5
46.4899965262764,-111.002950289408,6
46.4899361183366,-111.009640526966,6
```

Notice the header line.  It has an extra comma on the end of the line.  Is this a bug or do I not have a setting set right?  I'm running v 2.18.12.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a bug. Using 2.18.9, I can replicate it if one field is selected for the output (either if the source contains only 1 field or if it has several but just one is selected). As soon as 2 or more fields are selected, the ending extra separator is not there anymore.

Comment: How do we submit bugs to get them fixed?

Comment: @JasonSteffen [https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis)